# How to Modify TDS userid(uid) value using java API

Tags: ldap, tds

I am trying to modify uid value in Tivoli directory server using API. Please review the below user structure.

```
dn: uid=user1,cn=demo,o=evault
uid: user1
userPassword: {AES256}mIJFA1UiEMYP6J2dVt3vcg==
objectclass: top
objectclass: demoObjectClass
objectclass: ePerson
objectclass: inetOrgPerson
objectclass: organizationalPerson
objectclass: person
sn: user1
cn: user1
ibm-entryuuid: 134f18c0-b251-1034-8575-a2f4cc94f892
```

Here i am trying yo change the uid. Is it possible?? Please guide me on this

Answer (score 0):

You must perform a rename on the entry as uid is the "naming attribute".